# How do I create this effect hover?

Tags: html, css

I have this site:

[link](http://www.altradona.ro/)

**CODE HTML:**

```
<ul class="add-to-links">
    <li><a href="http://www.altradona.ro/wishlist/index/add/product/156/" class="link-wishlist" data-id="156"><span class="compara">++</span></a></li>
    <li><a href="http://www.altradona.ro/catalog/product_compare/add/product/156/uenc/aHR0cDovL3d3dy5hbHRyYWRvbmEucm8v/" class="link-compare" data-id="156"><span class="favorit">kjk</span></a></li>
</ul>
```

**CODE CSS:**

```
.compara {
    width:42px;
    background:url("/media/wysiwyg/COMPARE.png");
    color:transparent !important;
}
.compara:hover {
    background:url("/media/wysiwyg/COMPARE-HOVER.png");
}
```

I tried to create this effect hover but unfortunately not working.
It is a classic example ... I missed something in writing code?
The pictures are on the server.

Can you tell me please what should be changed?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: They used javascript mouseEnter and mouseLeave....and on mouseEnter they toggle hide and show the overlay...U cannot achieve using CSS

Comment: Change span to use `display:block;width:xxx;`

Comment: Can you give me an short example please?

Comment: of course you can do this in css!!

Comment: Did you look at the markup structure on that page with your browser's inspector? It's fairly easy to see that they're showing an overlay div on hover.

Comment: Can you give an explanation on where/how you view this part of the page? Using a browser code examiner (firebug) I noticed that it is not shown right away (hidden on load)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This Is What You Are Looking For:

```css
#cont{
  position: relative;
}

#cont:hover > #cover {
  display: block;
}

#img{
  width: 300px;
  height: 350px;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
}

#cover{
  width: 300px;
  height: 350px;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 2;
  background: rgba(255,100,10,0.5);
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<div id="cont">
  <img id="img" src="http://www.altradona.ro/media/catalog/product/cache/1/small_image/252x252/9df78eab33525d08d6e5fb8d27136e95/l/o/logitech-cordless-optical-trackman.jpg">
  <div id="cover"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

this effect can be created in css by having a hidden/opacity:0; element inside a container which holds you image.

I'm not sure you'd want to implement it as a `ul` as it doenst seem symantic to me but I have created a [jsfiddle here](https://jsfiddle.net/yLmza8xt/) showing the technique with a div

essential what you need is (in psudo)

```
container{
  position:relative;
  [dimensions]
}

container innerHover{
  position:absolute;
  [dimensions]
}

container:hover innerHover{
  [show the hover]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This key is the use :hover.

sample html:

```
<div class="box">
  <div class="innerbox"></div>
  <div class="controlpanel1"></div>
  <div class="controlpanel2"></div>
</div>
<div class="box">
  <div class="innerbox"></div>
  <div class="controlpanel1"></div>
  <div class="controlpanel2"></div>
</div>
<div class="box">
  <div class="innerbox"></div>
  <div class="controlpanel1"></div>
  <div class="controlpanel2"></div>
</div>
```

Sample css:

```
.box{
  width: 20%;
  min-height:400px;
  background-color: #777;
  display: inline-block;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.innerbox{
  width:80%;
  margin-top:10%;
  margin-left:10%;
  margin-right:10%;
  min-height:200px;
  background-color: #444;
}

.controlpanel1{
  display:block;
  min-height: 50px;
  margin-left:10%;
  margin-right:10%;
  background-color: yellow;
}

.controlpanel2{
  display:none;
  min-height: 50px;
  margin-left:10%;
  margin-right:10%;
  background-color: orange;
}

.box:hover .innerbox{
  background-color: #aaa;
}
.box:hover .controlpanel1{
  display:none;
}
.box:hover .controlpanel2{
  display:block;
}
```

see it in [action](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/NqYVbe)

Answer (score 0):

This cannot be done completely with css although you can create something similar. A few examples have been suggested. However, if you wish to replicate the effect, I would recommend using Jquery's AJAX functionality along with data attributes. `

```
$(".container").hover(function(){
    var $this = $(this),$info = $this.data("info");
    console.log($info);
    $this.html('Your html to replace on hover');
    });
```

Or some similar workaround. You can add data attributes such as link locations etc into your html.

```
<div class="container" data-link="target"></div>
```

And then in your Jquery code within the $this.html("HERE") you can add those variables so that every instance of the container has a unique output.